# How can I insert Image in SQLdb - under binary format

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got this db called Guild Logo (its for a game) in there I've got guild master's id + mark  + mark_jpg columns.

`Mark` is a `varbinary` column and `Mark_jpg` is a `varchar` column. The Mark field is usually filled with hex format numbers and letters - 0x001f52ae .... etc .

I believe I should convert the image to binary and put the output there. I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Here is what I've tried but it doesn't seem to work, because I get a bunch of useless letters which are not HEX.

```
<?php 
   $image = file_get_contents('assets/test.png');
   $imagebin =base64_encode($imagedata1);echo $imagebin; 
?>
```

Comment: read here for help http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.sql.doc/doc/blobs.html

Comment: I'd recommend you to store the file in the filesystem, rather than the database. It'll help keep the size of the database down, and I'm of the (maybe old-fashioned) belief that databases should not be used for file-storage.